# Accessing the elements of Tables that are stored in Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of Tables

```
Psilist = {psi0, psi1}
```

Where `psi0` and `psi1` are 2D tables. I would like to be able to call a specific element of the table in a specific element of the list. e.g. call element `[[2, 2]]` of the table in `Psilist[[2]]`.

I have already tried

```
Psilist[[2]][[2, 2]]
```

as well as using a dummy variable. I want to store the tables in a list as I need to iterate through various time-steps and to do this need to use values from the previous matrix. Any solutions or workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: tried `Psilist[[2,2,2]]`?

Answer (score 2):

What you tried should work. Without your full code, we cannot tell why you are having a problem.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(psi0 = Array[p0, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(psi1 = Array[p1, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Psilist = {psi0, psi1};

Psilist[[2]][[2, 2]]

(* p1[2, 2] *)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
Psilist[[2, 2, 2]]

(* p1[2, 2] *)
```